# getx remove value from list

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, flutter-getx

i am using GetX as a state management and i have a list declared inside a controller like this..

```
List<Chair> selectedSeats = <Chair>[].obs;
```

i have two methods inside to add and delete item to/from the list.

this i use to add the chair

```
  void addSelectedChair(Chair chair) {
    if (selectedSeats.contains(chair.chairName)) {
      return;
    } else {
      selectedSeats.add(chair);
    }
    update();
    print(chair.chairName);
  }
```

and this i use to delete the chair from the list..

```
final controller = Get.put(SeatController());


// this is how i call this method
//controller.removeSelectedChair(this.widget.customList[index].chairName);
//like controller.removeSelectedChair("C2");

  void removeSelectedChair(String chair) {
    selectedSeats.removeWhere(((item)=>item.chairName == chair));
    print(chair);
    update();
  }
```

but i cant get the remove to work...
why isnt it removing a chair from the selectedSeats list..

here is the chair model, if its any of use..

```
enum ReserveState { available, reserved, selected }

class Chair {
  ReserveState reserveState;
  int rowNum;
  int cNum;
  String chairName = '';

  Chair(this.rowNum, this.cNum,this.reserveState,this.chairName);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
selectedSeats.value.removeWhere(((item)=>item.chairName == chair));
```

also, it's not necessary to use an update each time, you can use the refresh method to rerender parts that depend on your array like this:

```
selectedSeats.refresh()
```

but do this if you are changing the internal value directly